# Introductory Topology True/False check - Topology without tears - Exercises 1.1

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I have just started to learn Topology, using specifically the book mentioned in the title. I have placed that information in the title with SEO in mind, if this is not acceptable practice in this community, please re/move it as necessary. I have studied the required MATHJAX and LATEX, and have hopefully written it to a satisfactory level. The questions are listed and my attempts or logic accompany them

If $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and $\tau$ is the discrete topology on $X$, which of the following statements are true?

$a) X\in\tau$: True - Required to be considered a topology.

$b) \{X\}\in\tau$: False - We have the set $a)$, but this is a set within a set.

$c) \{\emptyset\}\in\tau$: False - As above, but in regards to $\emptyset$

$d) \emptyset\in\tau$: True

$e) \emptyset \in X$: True of all sets

$f) \{\emptyset\}\in X$: False as of $c)$

$g) \{a\}\in\tau$: True since $\{a\}\subseteq X$ and the discrete topology takes all possible subsets.

$h) a \in \tau$: False $a$ would need to be a subset. See $n)$.

$i) \emptyset \subseteq X$: True, it is a subset

$j) \{a\}\in X$: False, true of $g)$, but here $a$ would need to be an element to be within $X$

$k) \{\emptyset \} \subseteq X$: False this is a set in a set.

$l) a \in X$: True

$m) X \subseteq \tau$: True

$n) \{a\}\subseteq \tau$: True, since this is a set within $\tau$

$o) \{X\}\subseteq \tau$: False, this is a set in a set.

$p) a \subseteq \tau$: False, this is an element and not a set.

Sorry for the large text wall. Please leave me a comment in regards to things I should avoid doing in my question, and/or any preferable formatting action I can complete. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have obtained a down-vote, I apologize for any inconsistencies with the preferred formatting of questions. Please give me advice so I can more appropriately post in future. It would appear my question did demonstrate research attempt and should be clear by my understanding.

Comment: (m) No, but I assume it is just a careless mistake. If we just reduce $X$ to $\{ a,b \},$ you can quickly see why this is false.

Comment: Your question looks fine to me.

Comment: @Nameless $X$ is a set, and it is within $\tau$, shouldn't this make $m)$ true?

Or is it that $X$ is an element, and $m)$ is equivalent to $\{X\}\in\tau$

Comment: (e), (m), (n) need attention.

Comment: @Topology, if $X = \{ a,b \}$, then $\tau = \{\emptyset, X, \{a\}, \{b\} \}$. Compare this with what you said in $(a).$

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you, this makes sense. My '$\in,\subseteq $' attempts were inconsistent. I understand now.

Comment: @Topology, yes.